# Viewport Shading glitchy weird thing

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, shaders, error

Why is it doing this? Every time I use viewport shading no matter what version I use this occurs. I've restarted blender. I've downloaded several versions both new and old. how do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: Radeon Rx 580 red dragon 8GB

Comment: It's most likely your graphics drivers. The latest Adrenalin drivers are causing issues for AMD users. You can either roll back your drivers to an earlier version, or try checking "High quality normals" under _performance_ in the render properties tab.